# Singly linked code explanation

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

I came across this singly linked list implementation in a book.  However, I don't understand some statements.  My questions against each statement are listed against each statement.

```
1 class Node {
2   Node next = null;  //Is this a constructor?
3   int data;
4   public Node(int d) { data = d; }
5   void appendToTail(int d) {
6     Node end = new Node(d);
7     Node n = this;//Why is "this" keyword used here?  What does this do?
8     while (n.next != null) { n = n.next; }//Where does "next" member come from?
9     n.next = end;
10   } 
11 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
2 Node next = null; //Is this a constructor? NO it is not. 
4 public Node(int d) { data = d; } //This is constructor
7 Node n = this; //The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class
8 while (n.next != null) { n = n.next; } //Learn Linked list
```